# How to address server response result in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, httpresponse

I am trying to Fetch User data from my server from a react application.

The login works fine and I can see the response object in the browser, including the access token.

The response.json returned by this function

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/url/api/manager/login", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const body = response.json();
      console.log(body);
      const token = body.token;
      console.log(token);
      setAccessTokenCookie(token);
      console.log(accessToken);
      if (response.ok) {
        //const bodyText = response.text();
        //console.log(bodyText);

        handleLoginBool();
        console.log("Login successful");
      } else {
        console.log(response);
        console.log("Login failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error logging in:", error);
    }
  };
```

looks like this:

```
[Log] Promise (LoginForm.jsx, line 54)
```

```
result: Object
```

```
manager: {_id: "6366495804b9c34feae0074d", name: "ManagerForTestMessageAddressedTo1", email: "ManagerForTestMessageAddressedTo1@web.de", password: "$2a$10$rHSfGfSlHWPJvFrT7vyBmeDB5K48K01pxUtgQCgK3IOfyz1FqkgTS", street: "default", …}
```

```
refresh_token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MzY2NDk1ODA0YjljMzRmZWFlMDA3NGQiLCJpYXQiOjE2Nzc4ODU5MTh9.8EaHGyWHvSepjYGOZKLv_mGgIj03WfKBKB…"
```

```
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MzY2NDk1ODA0YjljMzRmZWFlMDA3NGQiLCJpYXQiOjE2Nzc4ODU5MTh9.SWVp670AOHUboO33KvTpgfL60ljmnfAYWu…"
```

```
Object Prototyp
```

```
status: "resolved"
```

```
Promise Prototyp
```

in the browser. But I don't know and can't find anywhere how I can access the token and assign it to a variable.

Like you can see in the function I try to save the token in a cookie via Context API.

The Problem is, that I don't know how I can address the token. I tried everything I could imagine... I would be very thankful for some help.  Thank you already for reading this.

The Problem is, that I don't know how I can address the token. I tried everything I could imagine... I would be very thankful for some help.  Thank you already for reading this.

Comment: `.json()` returns another promise

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from @Daniel A. White -

`response.json()` returns a promise, so you'll need to add an `await`

```
const body = await response.json();
```